# A progress bar for long lasting function in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, server-sent-events

I'm looking for any reasonable  way to show the progress of some long lasting function on server implemented in PHP from the web-browser.

Recently, I found [this guide](https://limi.eu/projects/javascript/eventsource.html) using Server side events and it works quite well, but only if I generate lot of messages in small during a small amount of time. If I try to use the same working solution for fewer longer lasting steps, the browser almost doesnt update at all.

PHP function simulating lost lasting operation:

```
$big_number = 10000;
while ($i < $big_number) {
    usleep(200);
    sendMsg(++$i, "", $i/$big_number*100);
}
```

JavaScript log in the browser from function EventSource.onmessage(): (works as expected)

```
20:53:47 started, calling server
20:53:47 first message from server
20:54:01 last message
```

results in almost instant updates to the progress bar and feels good, but changing the values (instead of 10000 fast operations making just few long ones) breaks everything and the progress bar goes instantly after some break from 0% to 100%

```
$big_number = 100;                       // <- changed from 10000 to 100 
while ($i < $big_number) {
    usleep(20000);                       // <- changed from 200 to 20000
    sendMsg(++$i, "", $i/$big_number*100);
}
```

JavaScript log: (does not updates the progress bar at all)

```
20:53:09 start
20:53:19 first message
20:53:20 last message
```

Where do you think can be the problem, because these numbers are the only thing I have changed and it completely destroys the app?

EDIT: simplified JavaScript updating progress bar:

```
source = new EventSource(php_file);

source.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
    var result = JSON.parse(e.data);

    document.getElementById("myprogress").style.width = result.progress+"%";

    if(result.message == "TERMINATE") {
        source.close();
        document.getElementById("myprogressbar").style.display = "none";
    }
}, false);
```

EDIT2:
The problem might be in the buffering on server side (although I use no-cache, flush and ob_flush), but the interaction between the two mentioned cased is still weird (and still unsolved).

JavaScript log with server time included (in usleep(20000) version):

```
23:19:34 start
23:19:45 firstMessage (server time 23:19:35)    
23:19:45 lasttMessage (server time 23:19:44)
```

Comment: Please show the Javascript that updates your progress bar.

Comment: Can you try using the PHP inbuilt webserver? I.e. via terminal, move into the root folder of your site and execute  `php -S localhost:8000`. Then, execute the page as e.g. http://localhost:8000/test.html.

Comment: Just to clarify my previous comment: I tested the mentioned code and I get different behaviours depending on the PHP handler (mod_php, fpm, php inbuilt).

Comment: @FrancescoAbeni unfortunatelly this is on a webhosting and I dont have an access to a console.

Comment: I suspect the issue is with output buffering on server side.

Comment: @AleksG after every message on server I use ob_flush(); and flush(); - should I use something else? And why is there such a difference between  usleep(20000) and  usleep(200)?

Comment: Did incrementing the values result in exceeding the max_execution_time you had set?